# Directing error output from Bash psql

Tags: bash, amazon-redshift, psql

I'm using `psql` to connect to a Redshift database. Redshift doesn't seem to support `\set ON_ERROR_STOP TRUE` so I can't use that to stop the query and direct something to error output.

Is there another way to catch any error from a `psql` connection or query? So if the connection fails or the query didn't succeed, I want to just catch that an error was thrown and do another command.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your script ?
What do you mean by "not support `\set ON_ERROR_STOP TRUE`" ?
When you use that, you need to catch the return value like :

```
 psql yourDataBase -U yourUserName <<EOF 
    \set ON_ERROR_STOP TRUE     
    YOUR_SCRIPT az
 EOF
 ERRCODE=$?
```

So, `ERRCODE` will get value:

- 0 = success,
- 1 & 2 = database connectivity,
- 3 = script code error.